# POI Java Excel solution - Indentation value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, short, bit-fields

Hi,

It's my first experience working with POI (Java Excel solution) and I am trying to set the indentation in one of the rows to 17 as below:

```
CellStyle style = repSheetPositions.getRow(2).getCell(0).getCellStyle();
```

When I check the indentation's value is:

```
short a = style.getIndention();
```

**a = 15**

After I change the value to:

```
repSheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).getCellStyle().setIndention((short) 17);
```

and this time the value is:

```
short a = style.getIndention();
```

**a = 1**

Could you please help me?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that Excel 2003 has a limit on the maximum indention for a cell.  According to [this article](http://books.google.com/books?id=wvWrgnDyzqcC&pg=PT369&lpg=PT369&dq=Excel+2003+maximum+indent&source=bl&ots=ZBO6DwjgEN&sig=0wJd8pNmJxQozEvP7Z43J80kdGI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bV_6UtjGGOO92gW08oG4AQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Excel%202003%20maximum%20indent&f=false), Excel's maximum indention for a cell is `15`.

> The maximum indent value you can use is 15.

The `HSSFCellStyle` class must be taking this in to account by taking your value and keeping the remainder when dividing by `16`.  These are the outputs I get with different inputs:

```
15 => 15
16 => 0
17 => 1
18 => 2
31 => 15
32 => 0
```

However, when using an `XSSFCellStyle` (used for .xlsx workbooks, Excel 2007+), this issue disappears.  With an `XSSFCellStyle`, I can set `17` and get `17` back.

If you use Excel 2003 and before (.xls), then there's nothing you can do; it's an Excel limit.  However, Excel 2007+ supports indentions greater than 15.  The workaround is to use an .xlsx workbook so Apache POI uses an `XSSFCellStyle`, which will support `setIndention(short (17))` properly.

Comment: excelent! thank you very much rgettman! this works fine for me